# What is the power output for an OPO pumped below threshold?

Tags: laser

I'm trying to figure out approximately how much power will be output from an OPO when pumped below threshold (ie Pin=0.1Pth). All the research I've done turned to the same basic equation which only works for above threshold (~(sqrt(Pin/Pth)-1) which is always negative when pumped below threshold).

Does anyone know an equation I can use (or point me to a resource that can help) to figure out this problem?

Thanks,
John

Comment: Won't [Engineering](http://engineering.stackexchange.com) be better?

Answer (score 2):

Below threshold operation means that the gain inside the optical parametric oscillator is smaller than the overall losses. Your gain medium effectively changes the intra-cavity losses. Below threshold, the net loss is (still) positive and the system is (still) similar to an ordinary cavity. How much light will be transmitted, reflected and built up inside the OPO depends on the exact loss channels and magnitudes, keywords to look for are "under-coupled", "over-coupled" and "impedance-matched" cavities. A brief overview over these terms is given by Bond, Brown, Freise, and Strain, *Living Rev. Relativ.* (2016), doi:10.1007/s41114-016-0002-8, chapter 5 and particularly figures 28 and 29 therein.

If there is no input light at the lasing frequency, in steady-state operation pumped below threshold, your OPO will not output any light (at least no coherent state - instead, you will get a squeezed vacuum state, but that is a different topic).